# Creating tabbed div in xslt

Tags: xml, angularjs, html, xslt

I am using angular js in xslt. I want to create a tab based UI from XML.
In my usecase there will be a number of link and corresponding div based on the number of node in xml.
So for hiding and displaying the div I need some different data(may be an integer incremented every time) bind with every link created and same data I will put in ng-show condition of div.
What I did, I created a function that will return a number(++ everytime) I am assigning this number to a ng-attr-index of a link and in ng-show of div I will check it against a incremented number.
Now whenever a user clicks on a link I want to show corresponding div and hide rest of all.

```
 <xsl:for-each select="rendering/page">
    <a href="" ng-click="click($event)" ng-attr-index="getNextIndex()">
         <xsl:value-of select="@titleKey"/></a>
    <div ng-show="tab == getNextTab()"> </div>

  </xsl:for-each>
```

But `ng-attr-index="getNextIndex()"` is not working, not able to call the function.
Is there any way IO can do this?
or
Is there any other way I can implement this usecase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the XSLT side of the code and within the `for-each` you could set the attribute value as `<a href="" ng-click="click($event)" ng-attr-index="{position() - 1}">`.